# Excel power query group by: Get max of list values after removing outliers through Z score formula (((List Value(s) - Mean)/Standard Deviation) <3)

Tags: excel, powerbi, max, powerquery, outliers

Here is my whole power query code:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("D:\ElRezeiky Work and Reports\Detailed ITEM SALES Format\FILES"),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File"))),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Transaction Channel", type text}, {"Trans Type", type text}, {"Trns No.", Int64.Type}, {"Given Item Sales Value", type number}, {"Given Item Return Value", type number}, {"Item Code", Int64.Type}, {"Item Name", type text}, {"Trans Date", type date}, {"Total Invoice Sales Value", type number}, {"Total Invoice Return Value", type number}, {"Item Quantity", type number}, {"Unit Price of Item", type number}, {"Total Price of Item", type number}, {"Item Quantity Final", type number}}),
    #"Inserted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Branch", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Source.Name], " "), type text),
    #"Replaced HQ" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Inserted Text Before Delimiter","hq","الرئيسي",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Branch"}),
    #"Replaced RSHD" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced HQ","rshd","الرشيدى(السبتية-القللى)",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Branch"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced RSHD","abs","م.الجيش-العباسية",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Branch"}),
    #"Replaced Value3" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value2","nzh","النزهة#2 ش الأديب السباعى",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Branch"}),
    #"Replaced Value4" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value3","giza","م. الجيزة-ش مراد",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Branch"}),
    #"Replaced Value5" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value4","ain","عين شمس (ش.أحمد عصمت)",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Branch"}),
    #"Replaced Value6" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value5","bab","م.رمسيس (باب الحديد)",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Branch"}),
    #"Replaced Value7" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value6","hdq","حدائق القبه-ش.القصر",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Branch"}),
    #"Replaced Value8" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value7","shrtn","شيراتون#2-ش.جاد الحق",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Branch"}),
    #"Replaced Value9" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value8","shbr","شبرا طوسون",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Branch"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = #!"Table.Group(#""Replaced Value9"", {""Item Code"", ""Item Name""}, {{""Max Daily Sales "", each List.Max([Item Quantity Final]), type nullable number}, {""Average Daily Sales"", each List.Average([Item Quantity Final]), type nullable number}, {""Selling Days Count During Total Period"", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}, {""Median Daily Sales"", each List.Median([Item Quantity Final]), type nullable number},{""StdDev of Daily Sales"", each List.StandardDeviation([Item Quantity Final]), type number},{""Most Frequent Sales Per Day"", each List.Mode([Item Quantity Final]), type number},{""Average Top5 Daily Sales"", each List.Average(List.MaxN([Item Quantity Final], 5)), type number},{""Top 6 Daily Sales"", each List.MaxN([Item Quantity Final], 6), type list},{""Percentile 90%"", each List.Percentile(0.9, [PercentileMode=PercentileMode.ExcelInc]), type number}, {""Max Dily Sales Without Outliers"", each List.Max(List.Select(Value.Divide(Value.Subtract(each List.Select([Item Quantity Final], each _ > 0 ), each List.Average([Item Quantity Final])), each List.StandardDeviation([Item Quantity Final])) , each _ <3 ), type number}})",
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", {"Top 6 Daily Sales", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Values", "SS ((MAX-AVG)*Avg LT)", each (([Average Top5 Daily Sales]-[Average Daily Sales])*2)),
    #"Inserted Round Up" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "SS Method 1", each Number.RoundUp([#"SS ((MAX-AVG)*Avg LT)"])),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Round Up", "SS ((MAX*MaxLT)-(AVG*AvgLT))", each (([Average Top5 Daily Sales]*3)-([Average Daily Sales]*2))),
    #"Inserted Round Up1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "SS Method 2", each Number.RoundUp([#"SS ((MAX*MaxLT)-(AVG*AvgLT))"]), Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Round Up1", "SS (Factor*SQRT(AvgLT)*STD", each (1.28 * Number.Sqrt(2) * [StdDev of Daily Sales])),
    #"Inserted Round Up2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "SS Method 3", each Number.RoundUp([#"SS (Factor*SQRT(AvgLT)*STD"]), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Round Up2", "Selling Days Per 9 Branches", each Number.RoundUp([Selling Days Count During Total Period] / 9), type number),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Inserted Division",{{"SS (Factor*SQRT(AvgLT)*STD", type number}, {"SS ((MAX-AVG)*Avg LT)", type number}, {"SS ((MAX*MaxLT)-(AVG*AvgLT))", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

and here is my problem:

```
= Table.Group(#"Replaced Value9", {"Item Code", "Item Name"}, {{"Max Daily Sales ", each List.Max([Item Quantity Final]), type nullable number}, {"Average Daily Sales", each List.Average([Item Quantity Final]), type nullable number}, {"Selling Days Count During Total Period", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}, {"Median Daily Sales", each List.Median([Item Quantity Final]), type nullable number},{"StdDev of Daily Sales", each List.StandardDeviation([Item Quantity Final]), type number},{"Most Frequent Sales Per Day", each List.Mode([Item Quantity Final]), type number},{"Average Top5 Daily Sales", each List.Average(List.MaxN([Item Quantity Final], 5)), type number},{"Top 6 Daily Sales", each List.MaxN([Item Quantity Final], 6), type list},{"Percentile 90%", each List.Percentile(0.9, [PercentileMode=PercentileMode.ExcelInc]), type number}, {"Max Dily Sales Without Outliers", each List.Max(List.Select(Value.Divide(Value.Subtract(each List.Select([Item Quantity Final], each _ > 0 ), each List.Average([Item Quantity Final])), each List.StandardDeviation([Item Quantity Final])) , each _ <3 ), type number}})
```

To be precise here is my effort to find the value I need which is that I need to calculate safety stock so I need to get the maximum value of daily sales which is not an outlier so I need to calculate the Z score and find the max value with Z score less than 3, this is done by subtracting each value from the mean then dividing it by the standard deviation and find the resultant value with Z score less than 3:

```
{"Max Dily Sales Without Outliers", each List.Max(List.Select(Value.Divide(Value.Subtract(each List.Select([Item Quantity Final], each _ > 0 ), each List.Average([Item Quantity Final])), each List.StandardDeviation([Item Quantity Final])) , each _ <3 ), type number}
```

Here is my Example Table Before:

| Index | Source.Name | Trns Channel | Trns Type | Trns No. | Given Item Sales Value | Given Item Return Value | Item Code | Item Name | Trns Date | Total Invoice Sales Value | Total Invoice Return Value | Item Qunatity | Unit Price of Item | Total Price of Item | Item Quntity Final | Branch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Abbassia Branch April 2021 | Delivery | Sales | 162097 | 30 | 0 | 109548 | Strepsils Honey | 1/April/2021 | 50 | 0 | 0.5 | 60 | 30 | 0.5 | ABS |
| 2 | Abbassia Branch April 2021 | Delivery | Sales | 162098 | 34.5 | 0 | 112585 | Amigraine 30Tab | 1/April/2021 | 55.5 | 0 | 1 | 34.5 | 34.5 | 1 | ABS |
| 3 | Abbassia Branch April 2021 | Delivery | Sales | 162098 | 5 | 0 | 17714 | Cotton 50gm | 1/April/2021 | 55.5 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 1 | ABS |
| 4 | Abbassia Branch April 2021 | Delivery | Sales | 162098 | 16 | 0 | 118075 | Eva Rose Face Water Tonic | 1/April/2021 | 55.5 | 0 | 1 | 16 | 16 | 1 | ABS |
| 5 | Abbassia Branch April 2021 | Delivery | Sales | 162099 | 32.5 | 0 | 99385 | Orly 120mg 30Tab | 1/April/2021 | 48.5 | 0 | 0.33333 | 97.5 | 32.5 | 0.33333 | ABS |
| 6 | Abbassia Branch April 2021 | Delivery | Sales | 162099 | 16 | 0 | 2542 | Panadol Advance | 1/April/2021 | 48.5 | 0 | 1 | 16 | 16 | 1 | ABS |
| 7 | Abbassia Branch April 2021 | Delivery | Returns | 9681 | 0 | 153 | 97035 | Fito Gauze | 1/April/2021 | 0 | 153 | 0.6 | 255 | 153 | -0.6 | ABS |

HERE IS MY NEEDED TABLE:

| Index | Item Code | Item Name | Max Daily Sales | Average Daily Sales | Selling Days Count during Total Period | Median Daily Sales | StdDev of Daily Sales | Most Frequent Sales per Day | Average Top5 Daily Sales | Top 6 Daily Sales | Percentile 90% | Max Daily Sales Without Outliers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 109548 | Strepsils Honey | 3 | 0.649563319 | 458 | 0.5 | 0.445018409 | 0.5 | 2.2 | List | Error | ????? |
| 2 | 112585 | Amigraine 30Tab | 10 | 0.729726283 | 643 | 0.333 | 1.047153944 | 0.33333 | 9.2 | List | Error | ????? |

Comment: Please [edit{ your question and provide some sample data with the “before” and “expected result”

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I did So now